# In Power BI Desktop, how do I include an element on a graph that I had previously excluded?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

It's a pretty simple problem.

I am creating a graph in Power BI Desktop. I had previously hit the Exclude button on a field category that I did not want in the graph at the time (this field was blank), but now I do want to see it. How can I make that field reappear in my graph?

I have already tried removing the field from the graph and then inserting it back in. This only creates the same graph as before, with the previously excluded field still excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your visual and on the **FILTERS pane** you should see a group **Filters on this visual** with an **Excluded** section. Just click on the cross next to an element to undo.